# Консоль VSC не понимает русскую речь

Tags: java, консоль, кодировка, visual-studio-code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    System.out.println("Введи фразу");
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Твоя фраза: " + str);
}
```

**Результат:**
*Введи фразу

Привет мир!

Твоя фраза: ???? ???!*

Играл с кодировками VSC из-за проблем с выводом кириллицы при работе с классом Logger, ставил

> Бета-версия: использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем
> мире

в параметрах Windows 11 (что частично помогло, но дало больше проблем, поэтому вернул как было). В итоге стал явно указывать кодировку в *handler* и *scanner*, но при аргументе **System.in** в *scanner*'е это почему-то не помогает. А если использовать *scanner* для чтения файла, то кириллица воспринимается нормально
Уже голова кипит, не знаю что делать

Comment: Консоль Windows по умолчанию работает в кодировке cp866, попробуйте ее указать.