# В VS Code выводятся знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы после ввода в программе на Java

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-code, кириллица

Перерыл весь интернет, подключал нейросети, но всё одно и то же. Код логически построен правильно, без синтаксических ошибок, но когда я ввожу в консоль запрограммированное слово, например "пока" (см. код), то компилик воспринимает это неправильно и думает, что я ввёл что-то не то и срабатывает скрипт из else. Методом тыка пришёл к тому, что не поддерживается кириллица (в коде видно "hello" в первом условии, и при вводе hello код срабатывает правильно).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] greetings = {"Привет!", "Приветствую!", "Здравствуйте!"};

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Введите команду: ");
            String input = scanner.next().trim();
            System.out.println(input);

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")) {
                int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * greetings.length);
                String greeting = greetings[randomIndex];
                System.out.println(greeting);
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("пока")) {
                System.out.println("До свидания!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Неизвестная команда. Попробуйте еще раз.");
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Как питониста это знатно так заняло меня, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь, господа знатоки!

[image: консоль при джава]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1558815/178576), наверняка ещё и куча дубликатов имеется.

Comment: Стало быть Питон работает, Ява нет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так и есть

Comment: Указанная проблема НЕ воспроизводится: [ideone](https://ideone.com/mbSfCk), [GDB Online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/wP8Kmh9Rk), [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/VMJ) (названия класса изменены), поэтому возникают следующие вопросы: Как вы компилируете и запускаете этот код, в какой IDE?  Корректно ли выводятся сообщения на русском?  В какой консоли вы вводите кирилличный текст?  Что такое "компилик"?

Comment: Покажите как запускаете Питон, как запускаете Яву.

Comment: 1) Компилик = компилятор 2) Пишу в VS Code 3) при вводе в консоль  любого текста, код, который должен дублировать его в консоль выдаёт "?????". Питон запускаю через обычный питоновский лаунчер. Прикрепил скрины в основной пост

Comment: [Visual Studio Code can't encode cyrillic characters in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834398/)

Comment: Дело не в Java как таковой и не в классе сканнера -- это известная проблема с кодировками в VS Code.

Comment: @NowhereMan спасибо, надеюсь, поможет!